# Multiple rows inside a single column in jasper table

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am just a beginner in jasper report and i am stuck for a few days in a problem.
I have two tables

Medication {ID,medication_name}
and
dose_time{ID,medication_id,dose_time}

Applying

```
SELECT m.id,m.medication_name,d_t.dose_time FROM medication `m`
LEFT JOIN dose_time d_t ON m.id=d_t.medication_id;
```

gives me three result [image]

Now what i want is following jasper report

[image]

But i could stuck and can generate only following jasper format

[image]

My jrxml file is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="PracticeReport" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="67dfb372-a5be-403b-9007-61ab07fe88e7">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <subDataset name="Medication" uuid="1cccb880-701b-491e-8094-c133d4bd3819">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT m.id,m.medication_name,d_t.dose_time FROM medication `m`
LEFT JOIN dose_time d_t ON m.id=d_t.medication_id;]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="medication_name" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="dose_time" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <group name="id">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
    </subDataset>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="8bc54002-3e51-4bd6-8801-9856ef627b99" x="154" y="28" width="240" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Practicing Jasper]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="5976a679-e65a-4880-a9e7-74fd65f9e80d" key="" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="125">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Medication" uuid="5f6c54e4-9c5c-4120-8ac7-32793ec39d00"/>
                    <jr:column width="232" uuid="c5a6dca0-3be4-422f-8f13-4462d2e4caee">
                        <jr:detailCell height="124" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="080e50f3-23a0-4bf2-8d6f-b63618dfdc51" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="232" height="124"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id} + ","+$F{medication_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="232" uuid="b7bef864-31db-4b77-a929-a0d59e754b36">
                        <jr:detailCell height="124" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="7b3c68b6-6048-4690-b8e7-14a286f94297" x="0" y="0" width="232" height="124"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dose_time}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Please guys i need your help.

Comment: i am also facing same problem ..please provide some meaningful answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a crosstab for that. Go to Window and click on Palette. Than the palette will appear right. Finally, drag 'crosstab' to the summary section and fill in the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some help https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-merge-table-rows-repeated-values

In this solution, 2 datasets are used, the first dataset groups the data while the second dataset is used to create a table which is embedded in a band.

Edit: I applied another approach to do this. I used a table for the entire thing. The first column of the table is for the medicine and contains a textfield. The second column of the table is for the timing. It is a sub report and the sub report in turn contains another table with the timing.

I didn't use SQL but created a manual data in java. Here is my java code.

```
import static com.vroozi.api.requests.util.JasperUtils.compileJrxmlToJasper;

import com.vroozi.api.requests.util.JasperUtils;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PDFServiceImpl {

  public String generate() throws JRException {
    final String format = DATE_TIME_FORMAT.format(new Date());
    final String outputFileName = String.format("PO_%s_%s_PDF.pdf", "rajshree", format);
    final String purchaseReportsPath = "/home/oem";
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    Map<String, Object> cetamolMap = new HashMap<>();
    cetamolMap.put("medicine", "Cetamol");

    Map<String, Object> painKillerMap = new HashMap<>();
    painKillerMap.put("medicine", "Pain killer");

    List<Map<String, Object>> medicineMapList = Arrays.asList(cetamolMap, painKillerMap);

    Map<String, Object> time1 = new HashMap<>();
    time1.put("time", "11 a.m.");
    Map<String, Object> time2 = new HashMap<>();
    time2.put("time", "2 p.m.");

    List<Map<String, Object>> timeMapList = Arrays.asList(time1, time2);

    cetamolMap.put("timeList", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(timeMapList));
    painKillerMap.put("timeList", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(new ArrayList<>()));

    // Adding subreport for each medicine
    cetamolMap.put("timeTableSubReport",
        compileJrxmlToJasper("/subreport.jrxml"));
    painKillerMap.put("timeTableSubReport",
        compileJrxmlToJasper("/reports/subreport.jrxml"));

    parameters.put("medicineMapList", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(medicineMapList));

    return JasperUtils.generatePdfReport("/reports/report.jrxml",
        parameters, purchaseReportsPath, outputFileName);
  }

}
```

Here is the "report.jrxml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="catalogPOCR" pageWidth="559" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="559" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="42c67c01-6232-438f-8149-de04399dfcd2">
  <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
  <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
  <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
  <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
  <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
  <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
  <import value="org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils"/>
  <import value="java.util.*"/>
  <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
  <style name="table 1">
    <box>
      <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
  </style>
  <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
      <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
      <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
      <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
      <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
      <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
  </style>
  <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
      <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
  </style>
  <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
      <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <conditionalStyle>
      <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
      <style backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
  </style>
  <subDataset name="Table LineItems" uuid="183918c2-b66e-4347-ae7b-e891ab0a1d88">
    <field name="medicine" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="timeTableSubReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <field name="timeList" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
  </subDataset>
  <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="183918c2-b66e-4347-ae7b-e891ab0a1d88">
    <field name="order" class="java.lang.String"/>
  </subDataset>
  <parameter name="medicineMapList" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
  <parameter name="timeTableSubReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" isForPrompting="false"/>
  <background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
  </background>
  <title>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
  </title>
  <detail>
    <band height="170">
      <componentElement>
        <reportElement key="table 1" style="table 1" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="504" height="70" uuid="eb4057df-dd6a-40dd-870e-baac8c8afe17">
          <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="inch"/>
          <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="inch"/>
          <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
        <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
          <datasetRun subDataset="Table LineItems" uuid="8a44aec8-cdd4-4be3-b47a-620e00bb910a">
            <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
              <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{medicineMapList}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
          </datasetRun>
          <jr:column width="70" uuid="baa7f786-d12a-4234-b9d7-faef6c9f25df">
            <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
              <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
              </box>
              <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="20" uuid="5f84b7ac-c2fe-4426-b91f-6714b470a2bc"/>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="5" rightPadding="2">
                  <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                  <font size="8" isBold="false"/>
                  <paragraph rightIndent="4"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{medicine}]]></textFieldExpression>
              </textField>
            </jr:detailCell>
          </jr:column>
          <jr:column width="70" uuid="baa7f786-d12a-4234-b9d7-faef6c9f25df">
            <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
              <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
              </box>
              <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="62f0ab9e-28c4-4a58-935b-f98d26d600e3">
                  <property name="ShowOutOfBoundContent" value="false"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreport>
                  <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="48a7bbe4-b8ce-4a0d-a6e1-6ddd288e5602"/>
                  <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                  <subreportParameter name="timeList">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{timeList}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                  </subreportParameter>
                  <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                  <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$F{timeTableSubReport}]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
              </frame>
            </jr:detailCell>
          </jr:column>
        </jr:table>
      </componentElement>
    </band>
  </detail>
  <columnFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
  </columnFooter>
  <pageFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
  </pageFooter>
  <summary>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
  </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Here is the subreport.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="timeTableSubReport" pageWidth="559" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="559" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="42c67c01-6232-438f-8149-de04399dfcd2">
  <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
  <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
  <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
  <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
  <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
  <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
  <import value="org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils"/>
  <import value="java.util.*"/>
  <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>

  <style name="table 1">
    <box>
      <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
  </style>
  <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
      <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
      <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
      <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
      <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
      <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
  </style>
  <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
      <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
  </style>
  <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
      <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <conditionalStyle>
      <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
      <style backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
  </style>
  <subDataset name="Table LineItems" uuid="183918c2-b66e-4347-ae7b-e891ab0a1d88">
    <field name="time" class="java.lang.String"/>
  </subDataset>
  <parameter name="timeList" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
  <background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
  </background>
  <title>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
  </title>
  <detail>
    <band height="70">
      <componentElement>
        <reportElement key="table 1" style="table 1" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="504" height="70" uuid="eb4057df-dd6a-40dd-870e-baac8c8afe17">
          <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="inch"/>
          <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="inch"/>
          <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>

        </reportElement>
        <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
          <datasetRun subDataset="Table LineItems" uuid="8a44aec8-cdd4-4be3-b47a-620e00bb910a">
            <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
              <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{timeList}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
          </datasetRun>
          <jr:column width="70" uuid="baa7f786-d12a-4234-b9d7-faef6c9f25df">
            <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
              <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
              </box>
              <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="20" uuid="5f84b7ac-c2fe-4426-b91f-6714b470a2bc"/>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="5" rightPadding="2">
                  <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                  <font size="8" isBold="false"/>
                  <paragraph rightIndent="4"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{time}]]></textFieldExpression>
              </textField>
            </jr:detailCell>
          </jr:column>
        </jr:table>
      </componentElement>
    </band>
  </detail>
  <columnFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
  </columnFooter>
  <pageFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
  </pageFooter>
  <summary>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
  </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The output looks like this[image: pdf]

P.S. I didn't really pay attention to styling here. Hope this helps someone although I am 7 years late.

Comment: Could you please help to provide code for compileJrxmlToJasper() method that you have used in the java code?